Increase time efficiency when writing arrays to CSV file
I have the following code to amend two rows of "test_base.csv" with the entries of the arrays "a_temp" and "b_temp," saving the result into "result.csv." .csv files are here. It is working, but I'd like it to be faster. The total number of columns to modify is dim*dim, and dim = 100 takes about 6 minutes.
Is it possible to improve the time-efficiency of this approach? I am new to python, and this is a little over my head. I think obviously the repeated opening and writing of the .csv files will be slow, but I am not sure there is an alternative that could be faster.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# make two arrays
a_start= 0.001
a_end= 0.1
b_start= 0.5
b_end= 5
dim = 5  

a_vec=np.linspace(a_start, a_end, dim)
b_vec=np.linspace(b_start, b_end, dim)

a_temp = np.zeros(dim*dim);
b_temp = np.zeros(dim*dim);

k=0;
for i in range(0, dim):
    for j in range(0,dim):
        a_temp [k] = a_vec[i];
        b_temp[k] = b_vec[j]
        k += 1;
        
# write new arrays to the .csv file.
lines = []
myfile = "c:\\...\\test_base.csv"
        
### Loop the data lines to force all rows to have dim*dim columns.
with open(myfile, 'r') as temp_f:
    col_count = [ len(l.split(",")) for l in temp_f.readlines() ] # get No of columns in each line

column_names = [i for i in range(0, dim*dim+1)]### Generate column names  

df = pd.read_csv(myfile, header=None, delimiter=",", names=column_names) ### Read csv
df.to_csv('intermediate.csv',header=False,index=False)    

modFile = "c:\\...\\result.csv"
        
modifyIt(modFile, 20, a_temp, dim) # change row 20 according to a_temp 
modifyIt(modFile, 19, b_temp, dim) # change row 19 according to b_temp 

with the function "modifyIt":
import csv
import os

def modifyIt(myfile,row,array,dim):
    
    for j in range(0,dim*dim):
        
        with open(myfile) as csv_file, open(myfile+'.tmp',"w",newline='') as out:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
            
            for i in range(row):
                csv_writer.writerow(next(csv_reader))
                
            col = next(csv_reader)
            col[j+1] = str(array[j])
            csv_writer.writerow(col)
            for col in csv_reader:
                csv_writer.writerow(col)
        
        os.remove(myfile)
        os.rename(myfile+'.tmp',myfile)



It is unclear if a_vec and b_vec (and by extension a_temp and b_temp) are actual data that you want to put into your final CSV or mere examples for the sake of the question. In any case, it would be better to put their definition in their own function so it is easier to swap afterwards if needed.
Building of a_temp can be simplified by using np.tile and building of b_temp by using np.repeat.
Modifying (part of) a row can be done directly on the df DataFrame, you don't need the modifyIt function at all for this purpose.
Be aware that specifying names in the read_csv call may truncate the first columns if you happen to specify less names than columns actually in the CSV. Although this may not apply in your case as the CSV only has 2 columns to start with.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def generate_replacement_data(start, stop, dim, tile=False):
    """Geneare a dim×dim sized array by tiling or repeating a linspace
    of size dim from start to stop.
    """
    data = np.linspace(start, stop, dim)
    return np.tile(data, dim) if tile else np.repeat(data, dim)


def main(input_file, output_file, dim=100):
    a_vec = generate_replacement_data(0.001, 0.1, dim, True)
    b_vec = generate_replacement_data(0.5, 5, dim)
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header=None, delimiter=',', names=list(range(dim*dim + 1)))
    df.loc[20, 1:] = a_vec
    df.loc[19, 1:] = b_vec
    df.to_csv(output_file, header=False, index=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('c:\\...\\test_base.csv', 'c:\\...\\result.csv')


Thank you - time demand reduced from 6 minutes to a few seconds with the example of dim = 100.

Maybe I need new glasses but there is wasteful activity going on here:
with open(myfile, 'r') as temp_f:
    col_count = [ len(l.split(",")) for l in temp_f.readlines() ] # get No of columns in each line

Without even running your code, my IDE shows that col_count is unused.  readlines reads the whole file, parses it and returns an array of lines. You can imagine that on large files, this causes overhead and memory consumption. You seldom need to do something like this. readlines looks convenient, but it is sufficient to consume a file line by line (in a loop), rather than as a whole.
Since you are already using Pandas, having the CSV file loaded in a dataframe you could easily fetch the count of columns ie: len(df.columns)
Get rid of the dead code and performance should improve a little bit.

business domain
The first thing you need to do is write down
a description of the stakeholders and their desires.
Why are we doing this, and
how could we tell we did it successfully?
Write down a Specification.

amend two rows of "test_base.csv" with the entries of the arrays "a_temp" and "b_temp,"

Verbs like "amend" or "change" or "modify" are a little helpful, while still being very vague.
Tell us what motivated the problem, and how we can tell that we successfully solved it.
repeatedly re-reading
def modifyIt(myfile, row, array, dim):

First, PEP-8
asks that you call your function modify_it().
    for j in range(0, dim * dim):        
            ...
            for col in csv_reader:
                csv_writer.writerow(col)

Wow, that is a lot of re-reading and copying!
You didn't bother to write any # comments or """docstring"""
or use a helpful function name or describe in the Review Context
what you expect this code to do, so I can't quite tell
what Author's Intent was here.

dim = 100 takes about 6 minutes.

Yeah, I can readily see that.
There's a lot of busy work going on here,
unrelated to your business need.
If you'd told us about that need,
it would be more apparent how to tailor this code to the requirement.
Two bits of advice:

Keep your data in memory until the end, and then write it out just once to a file.
When repeatedly adding M bytes to an N-byte datastructure such as a spreadsheet, ensure the cost is proportional to M rather than proportional to N.

Maybe you want to hang onto the new data in a list or dict
until ready to write it out at the end?
The problem statement is a bit muddled,
so it is not yet clear to me what an appropriate approach would be.
You may wish to create a similar submission, with greater clarity,
as a new question.
